# Gauge animation on iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton, gauge

I'm trying to implement a gauge animation using (+ and - buttons) on iphone, but i have no idea where to start? Any help is really welcome. See the image below (this is what I'm trying to do). Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some open source code (with an example) that implements the gauge view. You of course would still need to do the buttons yourself, and possible add a different visual style.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/meterview

Comment: Thanks for the link, the code does not do any thing! When i run it i got a simple splitted view with two altimeters!

Comment: The code demonstrates how to create those two views. You would have to adjust the .value object of the MeterView object as the user presses the button...

Comment: Thanks Daniel, is there any tutorial on how to build this? Thanks aagain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rotate the needle based on the angle... Here is the logic 
You can refer my answer here... [Rotating a UIImageView around a point over 10 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768140/rotating-a-uiimageview-around-a-point-over-10-seconds/3770079#3770079)

```
    fireInterval = 10;
//Adjust starting and ending angle
    mStartingAngle = 45; 
    mEndingAngle = 180;
//Implementation

-(void) startTimer
{
 mPreviousTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}
```

In the loop

```
-(void) updateFunction
{
    NSTimeInterval timeNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

            //NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)) + NewMin
            //Mapping values between mStartAngle and mEndAngle
            mCurrentAngle = (((timeNow - mPreviousTime) * (mEndingAngle - mStartingAngle)) / (previousTime+fireInterval - mPreviousTime)) + mStartingAngle;

            if( mPreviousTime + fireInterval <= timeNow )
            {
                NSLog(@"10 seconds completed");
                mPreviousTime = timeNow;
            }
}
```

And rotate the needle based on **mCurrentAngle**....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the other answer is more appropriate in my case.